# "Invalid conversion" error with conditional operator

Tags: c++, ternary-operator, stdstring

I'm getting compile error in this line:

```
cout << (MenuItems[i].Checkbox ? (MenuItems[i].Value ? txt::mn_yes : txt::mn_no) : MenuItems[i].Value)
```

Error:

```
menu.cpp|68|error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'const char*'
menu.cpp|68|error:   initializing argument 1 of 'std::basic_string<_CharT, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string(const _CharT*, const _Alloc&) [with _CharT = char, _Traits = std::char_traits<char>, _Alloc = std::allocator<char>]'
```

MenuItems is std::vector of following class:

```
class CMenuItem
{
public:
string Name;
int Value;
int MinValue, MaxValue;
bool Checkbox;
CMenuItem (string, int, int, int);
CMenuItem (string, bool);
};
```

mn_yes and mn_no are std::strings.

Compiler is MinGW (version that is distributed with code::blocks).

Comment: Please specify a more informative title for your post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The two possible conditional values have to be convertible to a common type.  The problem is that the left of the outer conditional:

```
(MenuItems[i].Value ? txt::mn_yes : txt::mn_no)
```

is always a `string`, but the right:

```
MenuItems[i].Value
```

is an int.  It tries to find a way by going `const char *`->`string`, but then it won't allow the `int` to `const char *` conversion (which is good, because it would be meaningless).  Just do:

```
if(MenuItems[i].Checkbox)
{
    cout << (MenuItems[i].Value ? txt::mn_yes : txt::mn_no);
}
else
{
    cout << MenuItems[i].Value;
}
```

or similar.

Comment: I'd just add that the different overloads of `operator<<` are completely separate functions. A particular function call can only refer to a single function (or set of virtual overrides) in C++.

Comment: I did it this way and it works (but I had to take ternary expression after << in brackets)